# What Predictions can be done for Restroom/Washroom Data?

Tags: predictive-modeling, data-science-model, forecasting

My company has installed sensors, which actually monitors the Restrooms/Washrooms in the Building. Currently the sensors collect data such as Ammonia, Nitrous and Visitors Count;

All the data collected are time-series data and I have a huge quantity of those. My question is what type of predictions can be done that can add value to this business?

Can I use the power of Data Science to avail something which can make my restroom more smarter?

Comment: How can we suggest things that "add value to this business" if we don't know what the business is and what its income is. Do people pay to use these washrooms?

Comment: I believe the company does the installation of the sensors as it's USP and the analytics as a result of this..

Comment: The most useful thing data science could do in a smart washroom would be to predict when the paper is going to run out...

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site! In order to prevent from falling into common data science traps, I would encourage you to think about the following:

1. You should never take data at face value. You should be thinking about the transforms that you could be doing to your data to get more insights. For example, from the fields you have, you can also determine the time in between visitors, right? Can you determine the number of visitors per day? Also, what other datasets are out there that you can be tying together with your data?
2. You shouldn't be thinking about the business value of the data until you figure out what the data is telling you. This is where exploratory data analysis (EDA) comes in. You should explore your data and let the data speak to you (not the other way around!) so that you can be in a better position to think about your entire project.

Remember, the entire point of data science is to enable you to ask smarter questions. So, take the time to explore your data and figure what else you need. That will enable you to ask smarter questions and then declare some use cases for your business/client.